# Send lower level component prop up to App

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send a prop up to the top level.

At the top level I'm trying to console.log the event text

At the moment I do not want to use Redux techniques

## Here is the lower level component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui center aligned fluid container">
        <div className="ui inverted segment">
          <div className="ui inverted input">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="text"
              placeholder="Type Something"
              value={this.state.text}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## Then I try to console.log the text through an arrow function searchUsers

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Search from "./components/Search";


const App = () => {


  searchUsers = text => {
    console.log(text);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search searchUsers={this.searchUsers} />            
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

export default App;
```

## The Error I get

[image]

Please help me identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App component, you shouldn't use `this` and should use `const`
I think this should work

```
   const App = () => {

  const searchUsers = text => {
    console.log(text);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search searchUsers={searchUsers} />            
    </div>
  );
};
```

you can't use `this` inside stateless react component

Comment: when I console.log I only see the letter after I type the next one...So if I physically type Hello...I console.log Hell.......any way to fix that ?

Comment: use `this.props.searchUsers(e.target.value);` instead of     `this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text)`;

Answer (score 1):

Try this for index.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Search from "./components/Search";

const App = () => {
  const searchUsers = text => {
    console.log(text);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search searchUsers={searchUsers} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

export default App;
```

Edit:

> when I console.log I only see the letter after I type the next one...So if I physically type Hello...I console.log Hell.......any way to fix that ?

This is because you are passing the state as argument after setting the state. But setState is `asynchronous` so by that time the state is not set. You can either pass `e.target.value` or using callback in setState to  invoke `this.props.searchUsers`

For eg:

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  this.props.searchUsers(e.target.value);
};
```

This should fix your issue.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Option 1 did not work.  Option 2 would kill my overall application layout.

Comment: when I console.log I only see the letter after I type the next one...So if I physically type Hello...I console.log Hell.......any way to fix that ?